# Can't extract plex channels on lubuntu

Tags: plex

I installed lubuntu on a dust-old machine of mine to use it as a plex server. I'm trying to add privatae channels to my server but the OS doesnt let me extract the needed entry:(../var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-ins).
it tells me I don't have the permissions required to extract my files there. also I'm pretty new to linux and don't know how to use terminal commands at a high level. all help will be appreciated